# Convert array to double pointer

Tags: c#, arrays, pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting from a jagged array to double pointer in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890098/converting-from-a-jagged-array-to-double-pointer-in-c-sharp)

I wanna convert array to pointer in c#.

```
double[] array;
//input something
fixed (double* pt = array) {
//.....
```

It successed. But I want to use it like this

How can I use double pointer?

```
double[][] array;
//...
fixed (double** pt = array) {
//...
```

when I convert it to double pointer, it doesn`t worked.
How can I use double pointer?

(added) I already used "unsafe" at class like this

```
unsafe class Class1 {
```

and first example (using single pointer) was done well.
I wanna use double pointer

Comment: I think this might be useful for you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890098/converting-from-a-jagged-array-to-double-pointer-in-c-sharp

Comment: This code needs an `unsafe` keyword

Comment: @juergen d, why can't be this C#? Yeah, it is unsafe code, but possible.

Comment: `double[][]` is a jagged array (as opposed to a multi-dim array `double[,]`) and hence, is not a contiguous memory location. So it does not make sense to create pointer out of it. You perhaps need to fix out each individual array within.

Comment: Is this to simply iterate over the contents of the array?

Comment: possibly similar to: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890098/converting-from-a-jagged-array-to-double-pointer-in-c-sharp

Comment: @VinayC : Jagged arrays are the only type this is possible with.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, yes - I actually want to emphasis that jagged array is not a continuous block... so taking that address into a double** ptr does not make sense

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033054/fixed-statement-with-jagged-array

Answer (score 0):

Why not do?

```
foreach(var doubleValue in array) {...}
```

Its safe and simple. Idea lifted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9664138/659190).

If the array is jagged then perhaps a `SelectMany` would provide simple iteration.